# Akkusativ oder Nominativ

Tags: accusative, nominative

Ich habe den folgenden Satz in der Staffel "Friends" gehört:

> Das ist unser Wagen.

Ich glaube, dass es "Das ist unseren Wagen." sein muss.

Warum ist es Nominativ hier?

Comment: Warum glaubst Du, dass es "_das ist unseren Wagen_" sein muss? Welche Regel wendest Du hier an?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was du hier siehst, ist ein sogenanntes *Subjektsprädikativ*, das, zusammen mit dem Verb (das kann nur "sein" und "werden" sein), das Prädikat des Satzes bildet.

Das *Subjektsprädikativ* steht wie das Subjekt im Nominativ, gehört aber zum Prädikat.

Manche Leute bezeichnen das Subjektsprädikativ auch als "Nominativ-Objekt".

Wie oben schon erwähnt, kann ein Subjektsprädikativ nur mit den Verben "sein" und "werden", die beide hier als Vollverben gebraucht werden, stehen ("x ist ein y" und "x wird ein y").

> Mein Sohn wird Lehrer
>
> Unsre Oma ist Bundestagsabgeordnete

Comment: *Unsere Oma [...]

Comment: @PixelMaster "Unsre" ist eine vollkommen erlaubte und richtige Form von "unsere". Dein Vorschlag ist auch richtig, aber nicht richtiger. Und zu unsrer Oma paßt "unsre" einfach besser.

Comment: gut, Duden sagt, du hast Recht ^^ Hat sich für mich bloß umgangssprachlich angehört

Comment: Wikipedia listet 10 Verben auf, auf die ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ folgen kann: sein, werden, heißen, scheinen (zu sein), bleiben, gelten (als), (sich) fühlen (als), (sich) dünken (als), (sich) erweisen (als), (sich) entpuppen (als).