# Why nominative but not accusative?

Tags: accusative, nominative

Good Evening alles.

Warum ist der Satz, "Lars ist ein guter Lehrer." nicht im Akusativ?

Ich dachte, dass nach das Subjekt und das Verb die Akkusativ ist?

Maybe i am wrong but is there any reason why it ein guter wouldn't change to einen guten?

Vielen dank zu alles!

-val

Comment: Ebenfalls die gleiche Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39052/akkusativ-oder-nominativ

Comment: Warum erwartest Du, dass das Objekt im Akkusativ ist?

Comment: I suggest you reread [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/64515/6495) to your previous question. You simply need to learn the case of the object that is required by a specific verb. It has been explained to you that *sein*  requires a nominative object.

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix English and German in a question because then it's not clear in which language the answer should be.